# How can I change my multilingual urls from this example.com/index.php?lang=en to this example.com/en/?

Tags: php, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Somebody told me that `example.com/en` is more friendly than `example.com/index.php?lang=en`.
How can I change my URL last part from `?lang=en` to `/en`/?

(pd: I don't want to use gettext or any framework like zend to accomplish this)

This is how I'm internationalizing and localizing my web page:

(live example: [alexchen.co.nr/](http://alexchen.co.nr/))

lang.php:

```
<?php
function dlang($Var) {
 if(empty($GLOBALS[$Var])) {
  $GLOBALS[$Var]=(!empty($GLOBALS['_SERVER'][$Var]))?
   $GLOBALS['_SERVER'][$Var]:
   (!empty($GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS'][$Var]))?
   $GLOBALS['HTTP_SERVER_VARS'][$Var]:'';
 }
}

function language() {
 // Detect HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE & HTTP_USER_AGENT.
 dlang('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE');
 dlang('HTTP_USER_AGENT');

 $_AL=strtolower($GLOBALS['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
 $_UA=strtolower($GLOBALS['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

 // Try to detect Primary language if several languages are accepted.
 foreach($GLOBALS['_LANG'] as $K) {
  if(strpos($_AL, $K)===0)
   return $K;
 }

 // Try to detect any language if not yet detected.
 foreach($GLOBALS['_LANG'] as $K) {
  if(strpos($_AL, $K)!==false)
   return $K;
 }
 foreach($GLOBALS['_LANG'] as $K) {
  if(preg_match("/[\[\( ]{$K}[;,_\-\)]/",$_UA))
   return $K;
 }

 // Return default language if language is not yet detected.
 return $GLOBALS['_DLANG'];
}

// Define default language.
$GLOBALS['_DLANG']='zh-tw';

// Define all available languages.
// WARNING: uncomment all available languages

$GLOBALS['_LANG'] = array(
 'en',
 'es',
 'zh-tw',
 'zh-cn'
);
?>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
//proc all page display
include('lang.php'); //language detector
class Session
{
 var $lang;         //Username given on sign-up
 var $url;          //The page url current being viewed
 var $referrer;     //Last recorded site page viewed

 /* Class constructor */
 function Session() {
  $this->time = time();
  $this->startSession();
 }

 function cf($filename) { //function to clean a filename string so it is a valid filename
  $fp = explode('/',$filename);
  $num = count($fp);
  return $fp[$num-1];
 }

 /**
  * startSession - Performs all the actions necessary to
  * initialize this session object. Tries to determine if the
  * the user has logged in already, and sets the variables
  * accordingly. Also takes advantage of this page load to
  * update the active visitors tables.
  */
 function startSession() {
  session_start();   //Tell PHP to start the session

  /* Set referrer page */
  if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
   $this->referrer = $search = $this->cf($_SESSION['url']);
  }
  else {
   $this->referrer = "/";
  }

  /* Set current url */
  $this->url = $_SESSION['url'] = $this->cf($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

  /* Set user-determined language: */
  //set up languages array:
  //set cookie
  $langs = array('en','es','zh-tw', 'zh-cn');

  if(isset($_GET['lang'])){
   if(in_array($_GET['lang'],$langs)){
    $this->lang =  $_SESSION['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
    setcookie("lang", $_SESSION['lang'], time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
   }
  }
  else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
   $_SESSION['lang'] = $_COOKIE['lang'];
  }
  else {
   $_SESSION['lang'] = 'zh-tw';
  }
 }
};
/**
 * Initialize session object - This must be initialized before g
 * the form object because the form uses session variables,
 * which cannot be accessed unless the session has started.
 */
$session = new Session;
?>
```

localization.php:

```
    <?php
    include('session.php'); //language detector

    // determine the value of $lang_file according the one in $lang
    $languages = array('en', 'es', 'zh-tw', 'zh-cn');
    if (in_array($_SESSION['lang'], $languages)) {
        $lang_file = 'lang.'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php';
    } else {
        $lang_file = 'lang.zh-tw.php';
    }

    // translation helper function
    function l($localization) {
     global $lang;
     return $lang[$localization]; }

    // include file for final output
     include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

Comment: Your LiteSpeed web server provides [Apache compatible *mod-rewrite* support](http://www.litespeedtech.com/litespeed-web-server-features.html), so that's the way to go.

Comment: You should note that *Accept-Language* is a list of weighted values. The additional *q* parameters tell you the preference of that value and not its order. In fact, a *q* value of `0` means that the option is not accepted at all. That means you should better parse the list, order the values by their *q* values and find the best match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ModRewrite is your friend. Throw this in your .htaccess file. You may want it to go to your session page instead of index, then redirect with PHP. **Note**, this only works for *one* page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect languages
RewriteRule ^(en|es|zh\-tw|zh\-cn)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: @Jason McCreary Thanks for the reply. But how do you do this? -> "You may want it to go to your session page instead of index"?

Comment: I don't know your site structure, so I though you may want to set what language they are in the session. Do you have a multi-page site? This will simply redirect a request to a language sub-directory to index.php with the lang parameter set dynamically.

Comment: @Jason McCreary Yes my page has only as index.php, but how can I archieve the same effect for a page with more than one php file?

Comment: Architectures vary for that. Some have physical directories for each language and files copied within each. Some utilize subdomains, Some may use mod_rewrite. It just depends. The above is specific for your current one page site. You would need a stronger `RewriteRule` for a multi-page site. It would need to strip the language and append it to the query string all while maintaining the original request.

Comment: @Marcel Korpel Weird, I tested if mod_rewrite was working in my WAMP (it works), and did exactly what you said. But the url still index.php?lang=something.

Comment: @janoChen – 1. I'm not a participant in *this* discussion thread, so I'm not notified (I merely drove by; and yes, now I am ;-). 2. What did I say and where? You did mark this answer as appropriate, so what's the problem? If you enter e.g. `example.com/en/`, it should be internally rewritten to `example.com/index.php?lang=en`, according to this rule.